# Unity Array Index Is Out Of Range Raycast triangleIndex

Tags: unity, c#

I just tried the script from the official unity documentation here     https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html , the script is working at some point :

[image: Working 1]

But unity throw error "Array index is out of range" more often than successful click if i click at random place in 1 gameobject ( Cylinder ) :

[ i replay the game and do 5 click , see the error count at the debugger ]

[image: Error 1]

This is my script ( not important it is almost same with the documentation , but i just put it , and i removed some part to make it shorter) :

```
    RaycastHit thehit;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && methodoneenabled == true) {
        Ray theray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast (theray, out thehit)) {
            Debug.Log ("raycast work");
            if (thehit.collider != null) {
                string thedebug =  "Hit : " +   thehit.collider.gameObject.name + " ";

                 MeshCollider themeshhittwo = thehit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ();
                if (themeshhittwo == null) {
                    Debug.Log (" | themeshhittwo == null ! | ");
                } else {

                    Debug.Log (" | " + thehit.triangleIndex + " | ");

                    Mesh mesh = themeshhittwo.sharedMesh;
                    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
                    int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
                    Vector3 p0 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0]];
                    Vector3 p1 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1]];
                    Vector3 p2 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2]];
                    Transform hitTransform = thehit.collider.transform;
                    p0 = hitTransform.TransformPoint (p0);
                    p1 = hitTransform.TransformPoint (p1);
                    p2 = hitTransform.TransformPoint (p2);
                    Debug.Log (" | " + p0 + " ; " + p1 + " ; " + p2 + " | ");
                    Debug.DrawLine (p0, p1);
                    Debug.DrawLine (p1, p2);
                    Debug.DrawLine (p2, p0);
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

My script can be run so tell me if i missed some part when copying and pasting .

Can anyone tell me what is the wrong part and the cause of the error at the script ? -,- though the script is official script ....

Edit : the script i shared is located at CameraScript.Update()
Edit : the error is located at

```
    Vector3 p0 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0]];
```

but mostly will available at here too

```
    Vector3 p1 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 1]];
    Vector3 p2 = vertices [triangles [thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 2]];
```

Edit : i found out that the error appear if i click the middle of the cylinder , and work well if i click near the corner of the cylinder ( not the corner ! ) , also it is work well at plane mesh without error  , but what was causing it -,- .....

Comment: @CandidMoon , the script i shared is part from CameraScript.Update() , and the error is somewhere in script i shared , sorry i did not tell you that ! editing post !

Comment: Could you give us the line from your script? If you click the error in the console it should go to that line. That would help a lot so we don't have to read all of your code.

Comment: @JulianDeclercq i edited the post and explained the location of the error , and remember the error only show up sometimes , sometimes work sometimes not .....

Comment: The error is obvious, you can try to debug `vertices.length` with `triangles[thehit.triangleIndex * 3 + 0]`. You will get bigger or the same number, the question is how does it work and why, well here you are just asking to explain a very broad topic of procedural mesh generation and overall mesh construction. Check out some tutorials on this first.

Comment: @CandidMoon your description is not correct. For one, the whole purpose of the triangles array in a Unity mesh is to provide indices into the vertices array - it would be unusual indeed if the engine gave us a malformed array that contained lookup values outside the range of vertices.length! But more importantly, you can see in the screenshots that this user has already printed the culprit: thehit.triangleIndex is -1. More in an answer below. As you can see, debugging a specific problem like this is not a broad topic - it has a very simple answer.

Comment: @DMGregory yeah, you are right - I should be more attentive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already printed all the info you need - it's right there in your console output.

**Your hit.triangleIndex is -1.**

Since C# arrays start at 0, this will always be out of range.

**So, why would Unity give you a value of -1 here? Because you didn't hit a triangle!**

You've set up your cylinder with two colliders on it: a CapsuleCollider and a MeshCollider. MeshColliders have triangles, but CapsuleColliders don't.

Your ray hits the CapsuleCollider most of the time (since it's round, it tends to stick out beyond the facets of the polygonal surface), but then instead of working with the collider you actually hit, you've changed the Unity example script to use GetComponent to grab the MeshCollider, even if it's not the one you hit. This is not a safe thing to do.

If you want to ensure you hit the MeshCollider, you can do a few different things (in order from simplest to most laborious...):

- Remove the CapsuleCollider
- Put the CapsuleCollider and MeshColider into separate child objects of the cylinder, and put each onto a different physics layer. Then you can use a layermask with your raycast to select just the mesh's layer.
- Use RayCastAll to tunnel through your first colision and hit the next one to (and the next, and the next...) then you can search through the results array for the first one that hit a MeshCollider

Comment: WOW ! i really did not noticed it ! after i remove the Capsule Collider the error no longer appear ! thanks !